# Where can I find the settings file referred to in the VS Code PowerShell extension's troubleshooting page?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to find the “Language Server Protocol Payload Logs” for Visual Studio Code (VSC), per the [troubleshooting page](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#provide-language-server-protocol-payload-logs).

I also need to add the entry **"powershell editor services.trace.server":"verbose"** to the settings file, but don’t know what the settings file is called, or where to find it.

Can't find any documentation about either the logs or settings file. Would grateful if some could shed light on their locations and names under Windows 10.

Comment: To open the settings file, use the `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)` command from Visual Studio Code's command palette (invoke with Ctrl-Shift-P). You don't have to type out the command name in full: substrings will do for locating the command of interest, e.g. `user json` (although they have to be in order).

Comment: To get the logs, quoting from the linked page (which is specific to the PowerShell extension of VSC): "In VS Code you can open and read the logs directly from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) with PowerShell: `Open PowerShell Extension Logs Folder`." For the Language Server Protocol payload logs you'll have to follow the specific instructions [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#provide-language-server-protocol-payload-logs)

Comment: Tried that, got an error dialog saying the folder didn't exist. Can't find a way to display that dialog in here in stackoverflow. I'll see if I can paste it into my Github ticket (https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/4694)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at what people are doing in https://github.com/search?q=repo%3APowerShell%2Fvscode-powershell+services.trace.server&type=issues, I infer that the settings file being referred to is any [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) file- either your user settings.json file, which you can open with `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`, or your workspace .vscode/settings.json file, or a profile's settings.json if you are using a [VS Code profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles). Other than that, the rest of the documentation you linked is pretty self-explanatory:

> > While VS Code will not recognize and highlight it, it is a valid option and enables
> > tracer logs on the server.
>
> - Restart VS Code and reproduce the issue.
> - Go into the "Output" panel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> or
>   <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>).
> - In the drop down on the right, select "PowerShell Editor Services".
> - Copy the entire contents of the Output panel and paste it into the GitHub issue in the
>   browser. At this point, you may delete the setting if you want.